# Installing Levenshtein on remote server

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, levenshtein-distance

I'm just now toying around with EC2 and remote servers. I'm trying to install some Python packages and am getting hung on on the Levenshtein package. I get the error below.

I get that the issue has something to do w/ gcc and had read that I need XCode to get this installed but how can I do that with a linux server?

Thanks

```
sudo python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/requires.txt
writing python_Levenshtein.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing namespace_packages to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
writing top-level names to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to python_Levenshtein.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'Levenshtein' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c Levenshtein.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/Levenshtein.o

unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: New issue: ran 'sudo yum install gcc' which was NOT installed. Tried to reinstall Levenshtein and got this error...Levenshtein.c:99:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Make sure you install dev packages when compiling from source. Most packages have headers that can be installed with <package>-dev. Try installing `sudo yum install python-dev`